# Agular PrimeNG UI Library: how to implement a component that uses the primeng/api

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am still finding my way around Angular.

I want to use this component: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar

I created a component `menubar` for it.

Then I went to the `app.module.ts` file and altered it as such:

```js
//other imports
import { MenubarComponent } from './menubar/menubar.component'; //my component
import {MenubarModule} from 'primeng/menubar'; //the PrimeNG library component

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenubarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   //...
    MenubarModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note that I didn't add the line `import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';` with the imports (as specified by the documentation), because it gave me an error. The error seems to be solved when I add the import line inside the `menubar.component.ts` file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menubar',
  templateUrl: './menubar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menubar.component.css']
})
export class MenubarComponent implements OnInit {

  items: MenuItem[];  //error: Property 'items' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

  ngOnInit() {
      this.items = [
          {
              label: 'File',
              items: [{
                      label: 'New', 
                      icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                      items: [
                          {label: 'Project'},
                          {label: 'Other'},
                      ]
                  },
                  {label: 'Open'},
                  {label: 'Quit'}
              ]
          },
          {
              label: 'Edit',
              icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
              items: [
                  {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                  {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
              ]
          }
      ];
  }

}
```

As stated above, I have an error at the `items: MenuItems[];` part.

If it matters, this is the content of the `menubar.component.html` file:

```html
<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
```

I understand the error has something to do with [using an API](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menumodel), but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It is placed as a comment inside the second block of code. `Property 'items' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`

Comment: Do you have this property strictPropertyInitialization set to true in tsConfig.json?

Comment: Not that one but there are quite some parameters starting with the `strict` word so I am guessing it's one of them. But anyway thanks for asking, I remembered that most my issues are typescript issues and I am currently solving them with the `//@ts-ignore` before line. So I guess this one is solved for now :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a typescript issue (the error says so, but I missed it).

I am not sure how to solve the typescript issue, so I solved like this:

//@ts-ignore
before the line with the error.

And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is moving to more strict compilation.  So, you need to initialize like:

```
items: MenuItem[] = [];
```

or in the constructor.

```
this.items = [];
```